# Get IP from wifi hotspot in android

Tags: android, ip, wifi

I want to get the IP address of WiFi hotspot (from another computer) that android device connect via WiFi, **not the local IP address of Android**. I run application in **real device**.
I can scan all WiFi and get name of them.

```
public class WifiConnectorActivity extends Activity {
    TextView mainText;
      WifiManager mainWifi;
      WifiReceiver receiverWifi;
      List<ScanResult> wifiList;
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mainWifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        
        mainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver();
        if(!mainWifi.isWifiEnabled()){
            mainWifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }
        registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(
           WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        mainWifi.startScan();
        mainText.setText("\nStarting Scan...\n");
    }
    
    
      
    class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        wifiList = mainWifi.getScanResults();
        for(int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++){
          sb.append(new Integer(i+1).toString() + ".");
          sb.append((wifiList.get(i)).toString());
          sb.append("\n");
        }      
       
        mainText.setText(sb);
        }
      }
    
    
}
```

Of course, I can get the local IP address by use this code:

```
public static String getLocalIpAddressString() {
          try {
              for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
                  NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
                  for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                      InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                      if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                          return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                      }
                  }
              }
          } catch (Exception ex) {
              Log.e("IPADDRESS", ex.toString());
          }
          return null;
         }
```

For example, I can see the local IP address of the Android device is 192.168.2.101, but how do I get IP of WiFi hotspot is 192.168.2.1 in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all WiFi access points even have IP addresses!  It is not a requirement.  It runs on a different layer.

That being said, you can use reverse-ARP on the wireless MAC of the AP to get its IP address, if it has one.  Also note that this IP is sometimes different than the wired interface.

For home all-in-one wireless routers, you can also check whatever DHCP assigns as a gateway address, but again, this doesn't have a direct correlation to the access point.

Comment: Thanks! But the problem is I must use socket to connect it, unless I have an IP address, I don't know how to do (I try use wifi name but it does not work) Do you have any suggest?

Comment: Connect PC for remote it via wifi (such as shutdown, restart, remote PowerPoint slide...). I tried to use static IP for android devide (like above) and PC to test. It worked. The problem is I don't know how to get IP of PC from code.

Comment: You said you wanted to get the IP address of the access point, not the computer.  Do you want the computer IP or the access point IP?  You are going to have to prompt the user for the IP or hostname of the computer.  How else would they know what computer you were referring to?  The only other way is to send beacon packets, but this is generally not advised or necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. I use connectify program and make a wifi hotspot on PC. An android device connect to it. I can see the IP for wifi hotspot on PC is 192.168.2.1 and android device is 192.168.2.101. I just find this: I use PC name as host name and it worked, but it don't when use wifi name. Maybe it sound fool, but I don't know how to resolve that (make a new question for get PC name from android? or do something?). Anyway, thanks for help!

Comment: @R4j, the WiFi SSID (name) has nothing to do with TCP/IP, which is why you can't resolve it directly.  However, since the PC hosting Connectify will be using TCP/IP on the same NIC that is running in AP mode, you can use reverse ARP to get it.  You should know it's MAC from the wireless info.  You should post a new StackOverflow question:  "How can I use reverse ARP to get an IP address from a known MAC on Android?"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using default subnets then a host Ip address of `192.168.2.101` directly implies an access point address of `192.168.2.1`. Your IP address is group C. So for Any address `x.x.x.y` in this group, the subnet itself is `x.x.x.0` and the first host address `x.x.x.1` is assigned to the access point. All other addresses: `x.x.x.2` to `x.x.x.254` are assigned to connected hosts and `x.x.x.255` is the local broadcast address.