# Download file from computer connected via Wifi Hotspot using URL

Tags: java, android, image, url

I want to download an image file from an URL. My code works fine for any URL for an Image on the internet but I cannot find a way to download a file from my own PC, using its URL, connected via WiFi hotspot to my android phone. Is this even possible? If yes, please tell me How.

```
URL url = new URL("file://192.168.43.198/f:/ur/demo.jpg");
URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
conection.connect();

// getting file length
int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

// input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

// Output stream to write file
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/downloadedfile.jpg");

byte data[] = new byte[1024];

while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
    total += count;

    // writing data to file
    output.write(data, 0, count);
}
```

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561317/get-ip-from-wifi-hotspot-in-android

Comment: Nope! @AndyFaizan. I determined the IP addrress of my PC using ipconfig. This approach works fine for other network programs using Sockets. But not in this.

Comment: Ok. How about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906021/getting-the-ip-address-of-client-or-getting-the-informationssid-of-clients-con

Comment: Is it possible your computer's firewall is blocking access?

Answer (score 0):

Your computer will not react to a 'file:' protocol. On the internet you will use 'http:' so use that too here. Install a webserver on your pc to let it function.